# Cómo utilizar una máscara o similar al tomar una foto en IONIC?

Tags: ionic, ionic-framework

Estoy usando cordova plugin camera, y quisiera tener una máscara para obligar al usuario a enfocar su cara cuando sea tomada la foto. Algo así como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Muy interesante tu propuesta, pero, no debería tener la cámara, auto reconocimiento facial?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que el usuario enfoque su cara, pensando también en los celulares que no tienen esta opción.

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales luego de tener la cara de la persona intentaria aplicar otra libreria sobre la cara. estoy buscando hacer esto: Https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/Morphvideo-ape-bird-april12-2015.ogv pero las librerias que he encontrado piden definir los puntos de la cara

Comment: Por eso te digo que debe existir un tipo d reconocimiento facial y un par de cosas mas

Comment: pero no los encuentro o no sé si no los hay

Comment: Sinceramente no se si hay una librería de javascript que pueda hacer eso, deberías echar una búsqueda a ver que puedes encontrar.

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales si hubiera encontrado no estaria aqui XD

Comment: jajajaja, déjame ver que puedo ayudarte, que me tiene con curiosidad esta pregunta

Comment: bueno buscando encontré algo, me dirás si te sirve o que, una opción, es usar android puro, la otra es con cordova, aqui te dejo ambas, [enlace 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825778/face-recognition-api-for-java-android), [enlace 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605277/face-recognition-in-hybrid-apps-apache-cordova), [enlace 3](https://www.ezartech.com/blog/2016/9/16/ezar-adds-face-detection-for-cordova)